# How to set up libdgx with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, game-engine

I followed [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA) tutorial but it seems that it is kind out of date? I'm not sure.
Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with Java (but with C#, Python, ..) so maybe there is something obvious I did not regard.

IntelliJ is giving me import errors for libraries from the com.badlogic.gdx package

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
```

> java: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
>   etc..

Actually I would say there are some missing dependencies but this gdx-setup.jar should solve this problems already?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and just found the answer that worked for me.

Open your android skd manager from the tools directory of where ever you put the android sdks

make sure that Android SDK build-tools 19.03 is installed

if not install it

then go to intelliJ and from the menu bar open
View->Tool Windows->gradle

then hit the refresh (two green arrow)

Worked for me anyway.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Actually, the arrows are blue :)

Comment: This worked also.  Many inter-related pieces between gradle, studio/idea, android sdk.  I think I'll need to periodically check the android sdk manager for updates...