# "Error:(3, 24) java: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist", How to fix this?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm using intelliJ with libgdx.
I created a new project using libgdx and imported it to intellij.
when I try to build it I get this error:

```
Error:(3, 24) java: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
```

and other similar problems.
what could be the reason for it?

p.s
I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662095/how-to-set-up-libdgx-with-intellij) post about it but I couldn't found the gradle window and also I think that it won't help

**SOLUTION:**
The problem was that after I created the project using libgdx-setup.jar, Instead of using "Open Project" I used "Import Project" and it messed up the project.

Use "Open Project" after you create the project using libgdx-setup.jar file and in advanced settings check the IDEA checkbox

Comment: I would recommend that instead of editing your question and saying **SOLUTION**, you can answer your own question and mark your own answer as accepted. I would have up-voted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `gdx.jar` is missing in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I can't find this file.

Comment: strange...why do I need to do it? why can't the install of libgdx do it?

Comment: @AlexKapustian GoodQuestion. I think it it only used with the java api. If you do not use java you don`t need it.

Comment: I found the reason for all this problems...Instead of using "Open Project" I used "Import Project" and it messed up the project